# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream Postgresql 9.6

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Please, help me with this strange thing.

Yesterday without having any changes in code and DB I got an error when I'd tried to call endpoint: 
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream.

In the project:

- Hibernate v. 5.3.10.Final
- Spring-jdbc v. 5.1.8.RELEASE
- PostgreSQL JDBC Driver - JDBC 4.2
  42.2.5
- Postgers DB - 9.6

Entity like this:

```
@Lob
@Column(nullable = true)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private String payload;
```

I found in hibernate logs that possible problem may be in o.h.t.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor in extracting CLOB. The strangest thing that on dev-stage all works correct, but on dev stage we have postgres 10.1.

I've tried:

1. Added @Type(type="text") - main problem was solved, but I got
   CLOB id instead of real info in CLOB;
2. Added to @Column()
       columnDefinition = TEXT/CLOB  - doesn't work;
3. Added @Type(type="materialized_clob") or @Type(type="clob") - doesn't work;
4. Removed @Transactional from method that uses this entity - doesn't work;

On dev stage I see in logs:

```
TRACE o.h.t.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([payload4_0_1_] : [CLOB]) - [{"adId":2,"syncStatus":2,"syncErrorCode":0,"syncErrorText":"","crdate":"Sep 25, 2017, 7:16:25 PM","upddate":"Aug 28, 2019, 2:19:00 PM"}]
```

On another stage I see that if CLOB is null - it works, if not null - I get an error.

I hope somebody can help me, if info isn't enough I am ready to give additional info.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found possible root cause: Something was happened in DB and CLOBs were deleted and only relation ids stayed in DB.
For previous rows I get in the CLOB field something like 2341535, for current - real json-object.